# Perl: how do i get creation date and time of a few folders?

Tags: perl, directory

I'm actually new in perl.
I would like to know how do I get the creation date and time of a folder(or maybe more than 1)?
I have searched online and only modification time appears.
Is there anyway to do it?
thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Most common filesystems do not store creation date of files.

Comment: [`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html "perldoc -f stat")

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the specific file system type.  On POSIX systems, creation date is not generally available - all you can get is content modification, metadata modification, and access times. Some systems, such as the HFS+ file system on Mac OS X systems, do provide a creation date, but since it's not a standard feature, there's no standard API to get it, and you will likely have to take advantage of filesystem-specific, or at least platform-specific, code.